# Upgrading from 6.0.0 to 6.0.1 and then Umbraco goes back to 6.0.0

Tags: .net, umbraco, upgrade, patch

I'm having problem with patching my 6.0.0 to 6.0.1. I'm copying all files (I'm not changing any config file) installing as it should. When I come to backoffice after the install I can confirm it's verison 6.0.1. In the config file though, it's still says 6.0.0 and when I try to run the site it forces me to do the installation over and over again.

If I remove the 6.0.0 value in the config file I force Umbraco to set it to 6.0.1 and it's all fine for one page request. Thereafter it forces a new installation and goes back to 6.0.0. (I can confirm it both by verison number and the sorting feature where copied nodes have their old node names left when sorting.)

Is this a bug or am I doing anything wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like a bug - report it on umbraco.org

Comment: I don't know if it was a bug or me doing wrong but I solved it with some help. Link to question on our.umbraco. http://our.umbraco.org/forum/getting-started/installing-umbraco/38862-Upgrading-from-600-to-601-and-then-Umbraco-goes-back-to-600-

Comment: I installed Umbraco 6 using nuget without problems a few days ago - so I wonder if its only fixed via nuget?

Answer (score 0):

The installer should be updating web.config to show the version that is in use.  Does the installer have write access to web.config?  If not, you should be able to manually edit the web.config file to say 6.0.1 so it stops trying to run the installer all the time.

Comment: Hi! Yeah, if you look at the link to our.umbraco I solved it. About webconfig, it installed down from 6.0.1 to 6.0.0 so it wasn't anything about that. It had to do with nuget packages not being updated.